# ASP.Net MVC Model Binding Bug - Not Filling The Model Properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

When I submit the form, the Model in the Controller is receiving a Model incomplete. My Model has 12 properties, but only 2 of it comes with value (ID and Campeonato). All the others properties comes with zero/empty values.

Strangely, when I use (Form As FormCollection) instead of (JModel as JogoModel), the form comes filled correctly, but the JModel never works!

I have this model:

```
 Public Class JogoModel

    <Key>
    Public Property ID As Integer

    <Required> <StringLength(255, minimumlength:=5)>
    Public Property Campeonato As String
    <Required> <DataType(DataType.Date)>
    Public Data As Date
    <Required> <DataType(DataType.Time)>
    Public Hora As Date

    <Required> <StringLength(255, minimumlength:=5)>
    Public TimeCasa As String
    <Required> <StringLength(255, minimumlength:=5)>
    Public TimeFora As String

    <Required> <Range(1, 99)>
    Public Casa As Double
    <Required> <Range(1, 99)>
    Public Empate As Double
    <Required> <Range(1, 99)>
    Public Fora As Double
    <Required> <Range(1, 99)>
    Public GolEMeio As Double
    <Required> <Range(1, 99)>
    Public Dupla As Double
    <Required> <Range(1, 99)>
    Public Ambas As Double
```

And this view:

```
@option strict on
@option explicit on

@modeltype bets.Models.JogoModel

@Code

    ViewData("Title") = "Editar"

    Dim props = New With {.type = "number", .maxlength = "5", .Min = "0", .max = "99.99", .step = "0.1"}

End Code

@Using Html.BeginForm("Editar", "Jogos")

    @Html.Hidden("ID", If(Model IsNot Nothing, Model.ID, Nothing))


@<table>
    <tr> <td colspan="4">Campeonato </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td colspan="4">@Html.TextBox("Campeonato", Model.Campeonato, New With {.Width = "250"})</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2">Data:</td><td>Hora:</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2">@Html.TextBox("Data", Model.Data.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), New With {.type = "date"})</td><td>@Html.TextBox("Hora", Model.Hora.ToString("HH:mm"), New With {.type = "time"})</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="3">Time da casa:</td><td colspan="3">Time fora:</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="3">@Html.TextBox("TimeCasa", Model.TimeCasa , New With {.Width = "250"})</td><td colspan="3">@Html.TextBox("TimeFora", Model.TimeFora, New With {.Width = "250"})</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Casa:</td><td>Empate:</td><td>Fora:</td><td>G.M.:</td><td>Dupla:</td><td>Ambas:</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.TextBox("Casa",FN( Model.Casa), props)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBox("Empate", FN(Model.Empate), props)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBox("Fora", FN( Model.Fora), props)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBox("GolEMeio", FN(Model.GolEMeio), props)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBox("Dupla", FN(Model.Dupla), props)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBox("Ambas", FN(Model.Ambas), props)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="4"><input type="submit" value="Salvar"/></td></tr>
</table>
End Using

<div id="cap">@ViewData("result")</div>
```

And I have this action on the JogoController:

```
 <AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)>
    Function Editar(JModel As JogoModel) As ActionResult

        With JModel

            If Not ModelState.IsValid Then
                Return View(JModel)
            End If

            Try

                If .ID = 0 Then
                    Dim j As Jogo = Jogo.Cadastrar(CurrentLogin, .TimeCasa, .TimeFora, .Campeonato, .Data, .Casa, .Empate, .Fora, .GolEMeio, .Dupla, .Ambas)
                Else

                    Dim j As Jogo = Jogo.FromDB(.ID)

                    j.Campeonato = .Campeonato
                    j.TimeCasa = .TimeCasa
                    j.TimeFora = .TimeFora
                    j.Data = .Data
                    j.Casa = .Casa
                    j.Empate = .Empate
                    j.Fora = .Fora
                    j.Golemeio = .GolEMeio
                    j.Dupla = .Dupla
                    j.Ambas = .Ambas

                    j.GravarAlteracoes()

                End If

                ViewData("result") = "Dados salvos com sucesso!"

            Catch ex As Exception
                ViewData("result") = "Erro: " & ex.Message
            End Try

            Return View(JModel)

        End With

    End Function
```

Comment: What are the values you're entering for the fields that don't work?

Comment: More than likely, you are running into a culture issue where you are using commas or periods and the framework is expecting a different format for decimals.  You either need to set the culture for your app in your web.config as well as with jQuery if you're using client-side validation or you need a custom binder, such as described here http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx/

Comment: But what about the strings fields, like TimeCasa and TimeFora? Are they affected by the culture? See, the field Campeonato comes correctly even when I use specials characters like 'ãéõ'.

I'm just using an workaround, using the FormCollection and translating it to the model by Model.FromFormCollection(Form). But I'll try your suggestion. =)

Comment: That's not a "workaround"  That completely bypasses validation and is dangerous.  You still have not told me what the values you are submitting are...